# XSS persistent vulnerability

Tags: xss, jdbctemplate

Fortify scanner/profiler suggests the db output is tainted flagging XSS persistent vulnerability in the code below. It does not even have external parameters or concatenation! Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

```
public List<String> getExtensions() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
        "SELECT ext FROM document_type GROUP BY ext",
        new RowMapper<String>() {
            public String mapRow(ResultSet results, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return results.getString(1);                    
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not misinterpreting the results? This is probably the place where the XSS (stored by some other SQL) is loaded, but the actual XSS occurs where the data is put into a web page.

Comment: My impression is that XSS persistent is usually originated from DB, whereas XSS reflection is other way around from the web interface. 

You are right in that the  method implementing getExtensions() eventually puts unvalidated output to the web. The sequence is query_return()->getExt_return()->web interface, and the query_return() is marked by the Fortify profiler as the origin where the db output is tainted.

Thank you